# Android SDK is not installed, but Android Studio says it installed

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-manager

I installed Android Studio but in opening, the studio couldn't find the sdk.

[image: Missing SDK]

It's says right. SDK is not installed. So I try to install it, but the studio says, Android SDK is installed!

[image]

Now what should I do?